# Optimising long links for mobiles

Tags: css, mobile

I have a blog where I use the following link “http://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.0/js/TB.min.js”.

When I shrink the browser it breaks fine and all appears to be fine. When I view the page on my iPhone, there is a lot of white space to the right hand side of the screen and the only thing which protrudes over is this long link. I assume it is breaking the design for this reason, especially as my other blogs all look perfect on a mobile.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Use a link shortener service, like [goo.gl](http://goo.gl)? Instead of the link url, use a proper text for the link, like "Dowload"?

Comment: can you post your code or the or a test page ?

Comment: I am referring to a JS src line of code you need to change, as opposed to a link which you visit, which is why I haven't shortened it or used an alias. Thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 .css { text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

This will brake overflowing text into '...'s at the end

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: You have to add the other 3 rules for this to work, which then results in everything being ellipse(d)!